# Setting background image to useState variable causes it to become undefined

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When I had the variable `backgroundimage` assigned to `nightPlanetBoat` below, the image appeared.

However, setting `backgroundimage` to be controlled by `useState` inside a `useEffect` now displays a gray background. Logging `backgroundimage` returns `undefined` including on the first render. Does anyone see what is causing this?

The keys I'm using appear to be an exact match of the object keys I'm referencing inside bracket notation.

```
import nightPlanetBoat from './images/nightPlanetBoat.jpg';
import spaceGasClouds from './images/space gas clouds.jpg';

const backgrounds = {
  '/': nightPlanetBoat,
  '/about': spaceGasClouds,
  <more KV pairs removed ...>
}

function App(props: any) {
  const [backgroundImage, setBackgroundImage] = useState(nightPlanetBoat);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('props.location :>> ', props.location); // updates as expected
    console.log('backgroundImage', backgroundImage); // undefined
    setBackgroundImage(backgrounds[props.location.pathName as keyof typeof backgrounds]);
  }, [props.location]);

  return (
    <OuterContainer backgroundImage={backgroundImage}>
        <Nav bodyViews={bodyViews} />
        <main>
          <Switch>
              <Route path='/about'><About /></Route>
              <Route path='/contact'><Contact /></Route>
              <a few other routes removed ...>
          </Switch>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
    </OuterContainer>
  );
}

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);

export default AppWithRouter;

interface ExtraContainerProps {
  backgroundImage: string;
}

const OuterContainer = styled.div<ExtraContainerProps>`
  background-image: url(${props => props.backgroundImage});
  <other styles removed ...>
`;
```

```
// shortened package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.52",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: how are you importing nightPlanetBoat? Is the path correct?

Comment: @user3875913 I have addet it to the code sample above. It should be correct as it worked when directly assigned to `backgroundImage`

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it can be:

- nightPlanetBoat has a wrong import (do a console right before the useState)
- `setBackgroundImage` are updating as `undefined` but logs some value from your import only once.

alternative: if the idea is to use `nightPlanetBoat` as a default image when others does not exist, you could put it directly in here `setBackgroundImage(backgrounds[nextImage || nightPlanetBoat])`

Comment: Thanks, regarding point 1, the log appears correct: `nightPlanetBoat /static/media/nightPlanetBoat.617539be.jpg`. There is some strange number appended but I guess that is Webpack's doing. And as mentioned it workes when directly assigned: `const backgroundImage = nightPlanetBoat`. I'm looking at your 2nd point next

Answer (score 0):

This issue turned out to be a result of a type on the `pathname` property.

```
setBackgroundImage(backgrounds[props.location.pathName as keyof typeof backgrounds]);
  }, [props.location]);

// should be
setBackgroundImage(backgrounds[props.location.pathname as keyof typeof backgrounds]);
  }, [props.location]);
```